# Pack similar items into List

Tags: python

I am learning algorithms and there was this problem:

> Given an array of integers, pack consecutive elements into sublists.
>
> For example, given the list [4, 4, 1, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1], return [[4, 4], [1], [6, 6, 6], [1, 1, 1, 1]].
>
> Note: If there's only one occurrence in the list it should still be in its own sublist.

I have created the following solution:

```
def solve(nums):
    packed = []
    lastElement = nums[0]
    currPack = []
    for i, num in enumerate(nums):
        newPack = []
        if lastElement == num:
            currPack.append(num)
        else:
            newPack.append(num)
            packed.append(currPack)
            currPack = newPack
            
        lastElement = num
    
    packed.append(currPack)
    return packed

 nums = [4,4,1,6,6,6,1,1,1,1]
 solve(nums)
 # [[4,4], [1], [6,6,6], [1,1,1,1]]
```

It's working but as you can see it is not very clean. How can I improve this?

Comment: One-liner using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby): `list(list(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby([4, 4, 1, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1]))`. Also, if your code works, your question may better suit [codereview.se]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> x = [4, 4, 1, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> new_list = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(x)]
>>> new_list
[[4, 4], [1], [6, 6, 6], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
>>>
```

Another way would be:

```
>>> master_list, new_list = [], []
>>> for elem in x:
...     if not new_list:
...             new_list.append(elem)
...     elif elem == new_list[-1]:
...             new_list.append(elem)
...     else:
...             master_list.append(new_list)
...             new_list = [elem]
>>> master_list.append(new_list)
>>> master_list
[[4, 4], [1], [6, 6, 6], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [4, 4, 1, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1]
new_list=[] 
for k,g in groupby(a): 
    new_list.append(list(g))
```

`new_list` will be your expected result.